# PHP nested foreach loop iterate and set variable

Tags: php, loops, variables, foreach, unset

I got a problem with my variable within a nested foreach loop in php:

My variable $counter doesn't reset to 1 after the inner loop is done. I also tried to unset($co
unter) after the inner loop, which didn't have any effect either. I am aware that there is no inner scope in foreach loops in php. But I thought, once I set the $counter=1 after the inner loop is done, then the next outer loop and with it the new inner loop should start with $counter=1 again??

```
<?php
$counter = 1;
foreach($loop1 as $x){

     foreach($loop2 as $y){  
       if($counter==1){do something};

       else {do something else};           
       $counter++;
      };
 $counter = 1;

 }    

?>
```

This is the actual code:

```
<?php
$i=1;
foreach ($neu as $n) {
    $gcount = 1;


    echo'<div> </div>';




    foreach ($gesendet as $g) {
        if (($n["Quelle"] ==$g["Quelle"]) || ($n["Quelle"] ==$g["Ziel"])){

                if ($gcount == 1){
                echo nl2br("\n");                   
            }

            else {
                echo'<div id="divtoggle">' .nl2br("\n")."at ".$g['Datum']." ".  htmlspecialchars($g['username']). nl2br(" wrote: \n") ;  
                echo "\"".htmlspecialchars($g['Inhalt']). "\"" .nl2br("\n");    
                echo '</div>';                  
            }
    }
    $gcount++;
    }
    unset($gcount);
    echo '</div>';          
     $i++;  
}

?>
```

Comment: How do you know it's not set to `1`?

Comment: Because it doesn't execute the if($counter==1)[do something} during the second iteration through loop 1 and then loop 2. I also echoed $counter and it's only 1 at the very first iteration.

Comment: Provide the self containing piece of code so that we could run and see it ourselves. Provide the static definitions for `$loop1` and `$loop2`.

Comment: So you provided the actual code. How are we supposed to run it to reproduce the issue.

Comment: you won't. It's impossible to set up the whole sql query etc here. Guess I have to figure it out by myself then

Comment: Nope. You just should set up a minimum reproducible example with hard coded arrays (since the data source never matters). Actually not "should", but "may" if you need our help.

Comment: hmm..it seems to work now. I put the $gcount++; within the second if {}.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<?php
foreach($loop1 as $x){
    $counter = 1;
    foreach($loop2 as $y){  
        if($counter==1){do something};
        else {do something else};           
        $counter++;
    }
}    
?>
```

Comment: is the some recursion happening and it just looks like it's not resetting. can you post the full body of the function?