# php - inner foreach not resetting

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have already reserached about this but to no luck.

I recently visited http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php and tried to add `unset($var)` and `reset($var)` in the inner foreach but both do not reset the $var.

Last question asked about this is about 2 years ago and has also not helped me. Here is the link [PHP nested foreach loop iterate and set variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882793/php-nested-foreach-loop-iterate-and-set-variable#).

Here is my code:

```
@foreach($employees as $employee)
    @foreach($Users as $user)
        @if($employee->id == $user->user_id)
            @break
        @else
            <option value="{{ $employee->id }}" branch="{{ $employee->branch }}" department="{{ $employee->department }}">{{ $employee->first_name }} {{ $employee->last_name }}</option>
            @break
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

My expected result would be the list of employee options (can be found in `@else` portion of the code) without the existing users (`@if` part of the code).

My code only skips the first existing user. I expect four of them to be skipped.

I am using Laravel by the way.

Answer (score 0):

`break` will break the whole loop! Instead, use `continue`. Here is what happens. When you use `break` if the first employee matches the first user, It will break that loop and won't continue for next 4 employees!
If you will use `continue`, It will skip only those employees who are users too (true Part)! Replace `break` with `continue` and Let me know if it helps! According to your question, This must be it!

Comment: can you explain properly what do you want to do?

Comment: Already used `continue` sir but its not what I wanted to do. Correct me if I am wrong, In my current code, the `break` statement will stop the inner foreach and moves the pointer of the outer foreach to the next item. When I changed the first `break` to `continue`, all of the employee is being added to the `option` element.

Comment: Try using the condition `$employee->id != $user->user_id` and remove else part as well as `break`. See what happens...

Comment: What I want to achieve is to only get employees that is not yet registered as a user in the system. That is why I am looping through them (first foreach) and comparing them to the one already listed in the databse (second foreach).

Comment: Then use the answer Given by @Amr Aly . It will work!

Answer (score 0):

Reading your code, you have a collection/array of employees and a collection/array of users, and you want to display all employees that are not users yet. First step, am I right?

If yes, lets just assume `$employees` and `$users` are collections.

```
$employees = Employee::get();
$users = User::get();

//Get all employees IDs
$ids = $users->pluck('id');

//Get all employees that are NOT users
$ghostEmployees = $employees->whereNotIn('user_id', $ids->all());
```

In your view, you can loop through the ghostEmployees directly

```
@foreach( $ghostEmployees as $employee ) 
    <option value="{{ $employee->id }}">
        {{ $employee->first_name }} {{ $employee->last_name }}
    </option>
@endforeach
```

**Add efficiency**

As you only need employees that are not users yet, you can get them directly from the database.

```
$ghostEmployees = Employee::whereNull('user_id')->get();
```

If you still need all employees to user somewhere else in your page, get them separately

```
$employees = Employee::get():
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight  in getting them directly in database. Will do that in my end. But why is that my current code right now is not working properly? Please correct me if I am wrong, they I see a `nested foreach` is that when the inner `foreach` have met certain condition and when back to parent `foreach`. Its parent `foreach` will move its current pointer and again run the `child foreach` with its parameters reset.